# Underscore's debounce seemingly not taking effect with function calling an async function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, react-hooks, underscore.js, debouncing

I have some ionic segment buttons that essentially act as toggle switches. I'm trying to limit the rate at which the effects of the toggles can be switched/selected) and have tried Debounce & Throttle from both lodash and now underscores without success.

I'm currently using underscores and am still having the issue that the function is still being called freely despite the use of debounce.

Here's my code:

```
const SensorMeasurements: React.FC = () => {
//.....


const setOptionsHandler = (value: string, option: string, key: string) => {
if (value === "true") {
  console.log("RESULT: True / " + value + " / " + option + " / " + key);
  if (!settingsHandler(key)) {
    setControlHandler(option, false); //toggle on
    console.log("TOGGLE " + option + " ON!");
  }
}
else { // false
  console.log("RESULT: False / " + value + " / " + option + " / " + key);
    if (settingsHandler(key)) {
    setControlHandler(option, false); //toggle off
    console.log("TOGGLE " + option + " OFF!");
    }
  }
}

const setOptionsHandlerThrottled = _.debounce(setOptionsHandler, 5000, true);

const setControlHandler = async (input: string, notify?: boolean) => {
    let sysCommand = "";
    switch (input) {
      case "Reset":
        sysCommand = "R";
        break;
      case "Test":
        sysCommand = "T";
        break;
      case "Calibration":
        sysCommand = "B";
        break;
      case "Logging":
        sysCommand = "L";
        break;
      case "Trigger":
        sysCommand = "H";
        break;
      case "Measuring":
        sysCommand = "M";
        break;
      case "Unit":
        sysCommand = "U";
        break;
    }
    try {
      const abControl = str2ab(sysCommand);
      const dvControl = new DataView(abControl.buffer);

      //console.log("CONTROL BUFFER", abControl);

      await BleClient.initialize();

      //if (isAndroid && (devices.deviceId ?? true)) {
      //  await BleClient.getDevices(devices.deviceId);
      //  await BleClient.disconnect(devices.deviceId);
      //}

      await BleClient.getDevices(devices.deviceId);
      await BleClient.connect(devices.deviceId, (deviceId) => onDisconnect(deviceId));
      await BleClient.write(devices.deviceId, SERV_SYSTEM_CONTROL, CHAR_OPERATIONAL_MODE, dvControl);

      if (notify !== false) {
        present(input + ' Command Sent.', 3000);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      CatchError(error, "Disconnected");
    }
  }

  const settingsHandler = (string: string) => {
    return trueOrFalse(iTrueStates, string) as unknown as string;
  }

 const trueOrFalse = (array: string[], string: string) => {
   //check if string is in the array - returns boolean
   return array.includes(string);
 }

return (   
 <IonSegment onIonChange={e => setOptionsHandlerThrottled(e.detail.value as string, "Trigger", "statusSensorHighTrigger")} className="lowercase" color="brand" value={settingsHandler("statusSensorHighTrigger")}>
      <IonSegmentButton value="false">
        <IonLabel>Low</IonLabel>
      </IonSegmentButton>
      <IonSegmentButton value="true">
        <IonLabel>High</IonLabel>
      </IonSegmentButton>
    </IonSegment>
);
export default SensorMeasurements;
```

Why is `setOptionsHandler` still being called when the IonSegmentButton changes regardless of the debounce timeout? Am I accidentally creating a new  debounced function every time it's called?

Comment: I'm not sure if it affects the problem, but why is `setOptionsHandler()` declared `async`? It doesn't use `await` anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. It's left over from a previous iteration. I've removed it now. Thanks.

Comment: I think all the segments should be sharing the same debounced function. You would get different debounced functions if you called `_.debounce()` in the `onIonChange`

Comment: I just tidied up my code and removed the async. Then I noticed that the debounced function above is actually calling the next function which is also async. This function has to be async due to BLE calls to a GATT server. If I remove the async and comment out the lines needing await, then things function as expected. So it seems that async with debounce just spawns new instances of the function or at least allows debounce to be effectively ignored.

Comment: Post some more representative code that shows how you're using the asynchronous function.

Comment: Is this literally the code as it appears in your module? Isn't the JSX returned from a function? At what scope is `setOptionsHandlerThrottled` defined, relative to the function that returns the JSX?

Comment: I'Ve added in the additional functions relevant to this. Note: setControlHandler  is the function that requires async due to promises from the GATT server.

Comment: You do realise that you create a new debounced function (and reset the timer state) on every render, right?

Comment: @Bergi,I did ask that. However, the problem goes away if I remove the async / await elements from the secondary function. What would you suggest to remedy this?

Comment: That is… unusual. Maybe there is a difference in how you are setting state between the synchronous and asynchronous versions? I can't see a `useState` hook (or *any* state setting in `setControlHandler`) in your code though, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't set state. It sends a code to a GATT server. I also recently tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-debounce-promise and that sems to deal with this just fine. So it doesn't appear that I am creating new functions/timers on each render.

Comment: So you're saying that `<SensorMeasurements />` did not re-render when using the `<IonSegment />` control? Did you confirm this?

Comment: Ok, so I'm evidently get this all wrong. How would I go about preventing the debounced function from being recreated on each render? Actually this page seems to explain it well: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up using [AwesomeDebouncePromise](https://github.com/slorber/awesome-debounce-promise) as this worked best. In order to prevent the creation of a new Debounced function every rerender I wrapped the debounced function in a useMemo.

```
const setOptionsHandlerThrottled = useMemo( () => AwesomeDebouncePromise(setOptionsHandler, 3000), [iTrueStates] );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, the problem is that you are creating a new debounced function every time the component is rendered. The multiple debounced functions are unaware of each other's timeouts. If we omit the other code for clarity, the problem is relatively easy to see:

```
// This function is called on every render
const SensorMeasurements: React.FC = () => {
    //.....

    const setOptionsHandler = // ...

    // This constant is recreated on every invocation of SensorMeasurements
    const setOptionsHandlerThrottled = _.debounce(setOptionsHandler, 5000, true);

    return (
        // The onIonChange event handler is unique on each render
        <IonSegment onIonChange={e => setOptionsHandlerThrottled(e.detail.value as string, "Trigger", "statusSensorHighTrigger")} className="lowercase" color="brand" value={settingsHandler("statusSensorHighTrigger")}>
            <IonSegmentButton value="false">
                <IonLabel>Low</IonLabel>
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="true">
                <IonLabel>High</IonLabel>
            </IonSegmentButton>
        </IonSegment>
    );
}
```

The simple solution is to use a class component instead. By creating the debounced function in the constructor, it can be retained between renderings. Most other functions can be free-standing at module scope, since they do not depend on component state.

Do note that if the instance of the component is replaced as a whole (for example because a containing component is re-rendered), the timeout will still be reset. In that case, you might need to lift the debounced function into the larger component.

```
// Module scope, not inside component

const setOptionsHandler = (value: string, option: string, key: string) => {
    // Same as before
}

const setControlHandler = async (input: string, notify?: boolean) => {
    // Same as before
}

const settingsHandler = (string: string) => {
    // Same as before
}

const trueOrFalse = (array: string[], string: string) => {
    // Same as before
}

// Class component

class SensorMeasurements extends React.Component {
    setOptionsHandlerThrottled: typeof setOptionsHandler;

    constructor() {
        // This debounced function persists throughout the lifetime of the component
        this.setOptionsHandlerThrottled = _.debounce(setOptionsHandler, 5000, true);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <IonSegment onIonChange={e => this.setOptionsHandlerThrottled(e.detail.value as string, "Trigger", "statusSensorHighTrigger")} className="lowercase" color="brand" value={settingsHandler("statusSensorHighTrigger")}>
                <IonSegmentButton value="false">
                    <IonLabel>Low</IonLabel>
                </IonSegmentButton>
                <IonSegmentButton value="true">
                    <IonLabel>High</IonLabel>
                </IonSegmentButton>
            </IonSegment>
        );
    }
}

export default SensorMeasurements;
```

A possible alternative to using `_.debounce` would be to use the `debounce` operator from RxJS. In that case, a similar consideration would apply that you might need to lift the subject to a larger containing component.

In the comments, you stated that the problem went away when you removed the `async`/`await` syntax from the `setControlHandler` function. I cannot explain this; with your original code, you will create a new debounced function on each render regardless. I suspect some other, unrelated bug is preventing the event handler from triggering again in that case.

As an encore, I would like to show you a cleaner way to write your `setControlHandler` function:

```
// The mapping from inputs to sysCommands is entirely static, so you can
// define it in advance.
const inputCommand = {
    Reset: 'R',
    Test: 'T',
    Calibration: 'B',
    Logging: 'L',
    Trigger: 'H',
    Measuring: 'M',
    Unit: 'U',
};

const setControlHandler = async (input: string, notify?: boolean) => {
    // Replacing your switch pyramid by a property lookup
    const sysCommand = inputCommand[input];
    // Remainder as before
}
```

Comment: Also, I just tried the input command cleanup -which looks great- but I'm getting the following error on `const sysCommand = inputCommand[input];´ "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Reset: string; Test: string; Calibration: string; Logging: string; Trigger: string; Measuring: string; Unit: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Reset: string; Test: string; Calibration: string; Logging: string; Trigger: string; Measuring: string; Unit: string; }'.ts(7053)"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not familiar with classes in React and would have instinctively thought its bad practise to mix classes and hooks. The project is using hooks and the code given is actually just part of the larger page/FC.